# Two-Dimensional Array as Function Argument

Tags: c, arrays, function, arguments

How can I pass a two-dimensional array as an argument of a function (considered that the size of the array is known)? I will need help for both the declaration and the definition of the function. What I have in mind is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10
void function(int anarray[size][size]); //<- Is that correct?
...

void function(int anarray[][]) //<-Is this too?
{
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void function1(int anarray[size][size]); // <- Is that correct?
```

Yes, it is. `void function1(int anarray[][size]);` would work as well.

```
void function1(int anarray[][]) // <- Is this too?
```

No, that's a compiler error. Only the first (innermost) dimension of the array decays into a pointer when passed to a function.

Comment: could I say void function1(int anarray[N][N])? Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: @darkchampionz Did you read the very first line of my answer? I mean, "yes, it is" is quite enough, isn't it?

Comment: @darkchampionz The declaration and the defintion of the function must be compatible. Pick whichever type declaration suits you and use it consistently.